# What is the reason behind objc_sync_enter doesn't work well with struct, but works well with class?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

I have the following demo code.

```
struct IdGenerator {
    private var lastId: Int64
    private var set: Set<Int64> = []
    
    init() {
        self.lastId = 0
    }
    
    mutating func nextId() -> Int64 {
        objc_sync_enter(self)
        defer {
            objc_sync_exit(self)
        }
        
        repeat {
            lastId = lastId + 1
        } while set.contains(lastId)

        precondition(lastId > 0)
        
        let (inserted, _) = set.insert(lastId)
        precondition(inserted)
        
        return lastId
    }
}

var idGenerator = IdGenerator()

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func click(_ sender: Any) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            for i in 1...10000 {
                let id = idGenerator.nextId()
                print("i : \(id)")
            }
        }

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            for j in 1...10000 {
                let id = idGenerator.nextId()
                print("j : \(id)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Whenever I execute `click`, I would get the following crash

```
Thread 5 Queue : com.apple.root.user-initiated-qos (concurrent)
#0  0x000000018f58b434 in _NativeSet.insertNew(_:at:isUnique:) ()
#1  0x000000018f598d10 in Set._Variant.insert(_:) ()
#2  0x00000001001fe31c in IdGenerator.nextId() at /Users/yccheok/Desktop/xxxx/xxxx/ViewController.swift:30
#3  0x00000001001fed8c in closure #2 in ViewController.click(_:) at /Users/yccheok/Desktop/xxxx/xxxx/ViewController.swift:56
```

---

It isn't clear why the crash happen. My raw guess is, under `struct`, `objc_sync_enter(self)` doesn't work as expected. 2 threads accessing `Set` simultaneously will cause such an issue.

---

If I change the `struct` to `class`, everything just work fine.

```
class IdGenerator {
    private var lastId: Int64
    private var set: Set<Int64> = []
    
    init() {
        self.lastId = 0
    }
    
    func nextId() -> Int64 {
        objc_sync_enter(self)
        defer {
            objc_sync_exit(self)
        }
        
        repeat {
            lastId = lastId + 1
        } while set.contains(lastId)

        precondition(lastId > 0)
        
        let (inserted, _) = set.insert(lastId)
        precondition(inserted)
        
        return lastId
    }
}
```

---

May I know what is the reason behind? Why the above `objc_sync_enter` works well in `class`, but not in `struct`?

Comment: I feel like it's mis-annotated. It should accept an `AnyObject`, not an `Any`. The issue is that it's using a value's memory location as a proxy for identity, which is only true for instances of classes. Structs don't have a stable identity (they're copied when passed, assigned, etc.)

Comment: Although I would caution against using a lock-based ID generator like this, anyway, depending on how many IDs you need. It might be best to have a thread-local (or Task-local) ID generator that pulls from a batch of IDs  (which can be done without locking), so you only need to synchronize every time you assign a batch of IDs.

Comment: @Alexander Even if it took `AnyObject`, the result would be the same — all Swift values are convertible to `AnyObject` on Darwin platforms, including structs.

Comment: @ItaiFerber Oh yeah, right. Gosh, I really do think that was a mistake, given how object-identity-sensitive so many ObjC APIs are.

Comment: @Alexander Yeah… Add to the long list of things that would have been differently if Obj-C interop wasn’t a strict requirement…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `objc_sync_enter`/`objc_sync_exit` functions take an object instance and use its identity (i.e., address in memory) in order to allocate and associate a lock in memory — and use that lock to protect the code between the `enter` and `exit` calls.

However, `struct`s are not objects, and don't have reference semantics which would allow them to be used in this way — they're not even guaranteed to be allocated in a stable location in memory. However, to support interoperation with Objective-C, `struct`s *must* have a consistent object-like representation when used from Objective-C, or else calling Objective-C code with, say, a `struct` inside of an `Any` instance could trigger undefined behavior.

When a `struct` is passed to Objective-C in the guise of an object (e.g., inside of `Any`, or `AnyObject`), it is wrapped up in a *temporary* object of a private class type called `__SwiftValue`. This allows it to *look* like an object to Objective-C, and in some cases, be used like an object, but critically, it is *not* a long-lived, stable object.

You can see this with the following code:

```swift
struct Foo {}
let f = Foo()
print(f) // => Foo()
print(f as AnyObject) // => __SwiftValue

print(ObjectIdentifier(f as AnyObject)) // => ObjectIdentifier(0x0000600002595900)
print(ObjectIdentifier(f as AnyObject)) // => ObjectIdentifier(0x0000600002595c60)
```

The pointers will change run to run, but you can see that every time `f` is accessed as an `AnyObject`, it will have a *new* address.

This means that when you call `objc_sync_enter` on a `struct`, a new `__SwiftValue` object will be created to wrap your `struct`, and *that* object is passed in to `objc_sync_enter`. `objc_sync_enter` will then associate a new lock with the temporary object value which was automatically created for you... and then that object is immediately deallocated. This means two major things:

1. When you call `objc_sync_exit`, a *new* object will be created and passed in, but the runtime has no lock associated with that new object instance! It may crash at this point.
2. *Every time* you call `objc_sync_enter`, you're creating a new, separate lock... which means that there's effectively no synchronization at all: every thread is getting a new lock altogether.

This new pointer instance isn't guaranteed — depending on optimization, the object *may* live long enough to be reused across `objc_sync_*` calls, or a new object could be allocated exactly in the same place as an old one... or a new object could be allocated where a *different* struct used to be, and you accidentally unlock a different thread...

All of this means that you should definitely avoid using `objc_sync_enter`/`objc_sync_exit` as a locking mechanism from Swift, and switch over to something like [`NSLock`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslock), an *allocated* [`os_unfair_lock`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/1646466-os_unfair_lock_lock), or even a `DispatchQueue`, which are well-supported from Swift. (Really, the `objc_sync_*` functions are primitives for use largely by the Obj-C runtime only, and probably should be un-exposed to Swift.)